Find matrix that optimally equalizes the norm of a set of vectors
I recently came across the following problem: Given is a set of $N$ vectors $\mathbf{v}_i \in \mathbb{C}^3$. I want to find the matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$ such that the vector norms $||\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}_i||_2$ are as close together as possible. One way to address this problem would be to formulate it as the following optimization problem for a given constant $b\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\mathbf{A}=
\underset{\mathbf{A'}}{\mathrm{argmin}}
\quad\sum _i \left( || \mathbf{A'}\mathbf{v}_i ||_2^2-b^2 \right)^2
$$
I was wondering if the problem above can be solved analytically or if there is a way to cast the the original problem into an optimization problem that can be solved analytically?

summation is missed? any properties of those $\mathbf{v}_i$?

Hello, yes, I forgot the summation. There are no specific properties to the $\mathbf{v}_i$.

I guess the original task maybe formulated as minmax problem, which is not equivalent to yours for a general $b$. For your formulation, there might be no analytic solution in general. How many $v_i$?

Is $\mathbf A=\mathbf 0$ invalid for some reason? For that matter, it looks like any solution $\mathbf A\neq 0$ would be surpassed by $\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf A$.

What does differentiating with respect to $A$ yield?

The number N is 24 for the particular application I am interested in. I can give some context on where this problem stems from: I have a sensor which measures a magnetic field phasor $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{C}^3$. The sensor outputs a signal $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^3=\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}$. I am interested in identifying the Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ experimentally. To do so I expose the sensor to a magnetic field phasor whose magnitude $b=|\mathbf{b}|$ I can control accurately. I then rotate the sensor into different orientations and for each orientation I measure a $\mathbf{v}_i$.

@Angelica why 0.5A is better than A?

@Mantabit Thanks, I would suggest you adding the background information to your OP.

@Mantabit Do you only know $|\mathbf{b}|_2^2$ or do you know $\mathbf{b}$ itself? In the latter case, you could use $\sum_i | \mathbf{A}'\mathbf{v}_i-\mathbf{b}|_2^2$. This should lead to a simpler problem that should have a solution given by a pseudo-inverse.

@MarcDinh the one you suggested is a completely different problem

@goldboy I know the problem I suggested is different. Basically, I am only asking if the modeling is what the OP really wants. From the comment, I understand that $\mathbf{Av}=\mathbf{b}$ which implies $|\mathbf{Av}|_2^2=|\mathbf{b}|_2^2$. But the converse is not true. But obviously, I cannot know what the OP really wants. Hence, a suggestion.

@MarcDinh OP explained the context of the formulated problem in the previous comment
